# What is C# equivalent for Calendar.get() method in Java?

Tags: c#, java

Does anyone know the C# equivalent for the following java code?

```
int offset = calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + calendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
```

calendar is an instance of Calendar Object.

Comment: It may be helpful for those that don't know C# to give a summary of what the code does, so people who are familiar with C#/.NET can give you an answer easier.

Comment: The code is meant to generate a UTC timezone offset, like -0800 for PST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out the [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class as a starting point in helping yourself in converting the Java code into C# code.  Hint: `TimeZoneInfo.Local` gives you the local time zone for the system the code is executing on.

Answer (score 0):

[DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) may be worth a look, you can get the offset from there